# How Can I get UDP messages coming on eth with openHAB?

Tags: openhab

I'm able to send UDP message to the remote IP node on eth with openHAB using the binding tcp/udp, i.e.:

udp=">[ON:10.44.212.60:3000:'MAP(mydevice.map)'],

> [OFF:10.44.212.60:3000:'MAP(mydevice.map)']"

But I do not have idea what I have to do to get and store the response coming back.

Please who can help?

Thanks and regards

marco

Answer (score 1):

Not possibile UTP is one-way communication, you will have to use TCP protocol.

Comment: Your statement about UDP is right, but if the receiver reacts on the received UDP packet by sending an UDP answer it is the case marco_m asked for.